# Nested routes causing issues with my forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have my nested route setup as follows:

```
  resources :clients do
    resources :contacts
  end
```

and my update action form as so:

```
= form_for @contact, :url => client_contacts_path(@contact.client), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
```

however when I go to save I get this error:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/clients/3/contacts"
```

I'm not quite sure why it isn't trying the route: /clients/3/contacts/:id

what am i missing from my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your **form_for** call to:

```
= form_for [@client, @contact], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
```

Rails will figure out all it need by it self:

- when @contact is a new record it will generate **/clients/:client_id/contacts/new** url
- when @contact already exist it will generate **/clients/:client_id/contacts/:id/edit** url

More info about [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).